# Auto Populate Second Dropdown list items after selection on first dropdown list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, dotnetnuke-6

I'm using DNN on our intranet. We have configured form and list module to track/update inventory records.

Currently I have two fields named MainCompany and SubCompany. MainCompany has 15 items and each items at MainCompany has many subitems (up to 50).

DotNetNuke (DNN) renders MainCompany and SubCompany as dropdown lists (this is good). However, I couldn't find a way to populate items on SubCompany automatically.

For instance; You would select United States from Country dropdown list and regions of US would be displayed. In our case, all items are displayed regardless of choice at first select list.

Our html render items like:

```
<select name="MainCompany" id="MainCompany">
<option value="0" class="DNNRadioButton">Not Specified</option>
<option value="1" class="DNNRadioButton">Company A</option>
<option value="2" class="DNNRadioButton">Company B</option>

<select name="SubCompany" id="SubCompany">
<option value="0" class="DNNRadioButton">Not Specified</option>
<option value="1" class="DNNRadioButton">SubCompany A</option>
<option value="2" class="DNNRadioButton">SubCompany B</option>
<option value="3" class="DNNRadioButton">SubCompany c</option>
<option value="4" class="DNNRadioButton">SubCompany D</option>
```

SubCompany A and SubCompany B is sub companies of  Main Company A; SubCompany C and SubCompany D sub companies of  Main Company B.

The list is long but I tried to explain things shortly.

On the MSSQL database all values and captions (e.g SubCompany A) stored in a table named FieldSettings at InputSettings column in following format:

For MainCompany: `None Specified|0;Company A|1;Company B|2;.....Company Z|n`
For SubCompany : `None Specified|0;SubCompany A|1;SubCompany B|2;.....SubCompany  Z|n`

Since values have no connection at database level, I am looking for ways to connect them at HTML level, if not by using code.

The module we are using is Form and List Module and source code can be downloaded from
http://dnnfnl.codeplex.com/releases/view/93728

After form is submitted, records (e.g SubCompany A and Company A) recorded in UserDefinedTable table like below:

```
FieldID || RowId || FieldValue
----------------------------------
113        2323     MainCompany A
114        2324     SubCompany A
```

I am working at a restrictive intranet and I couldn't provide more information. I appreciate your help.

Comment: in case you have a lot of this kind of things there's a library for that, here's the demo for it: http://demowf.aspnetawesome.com/AjaxDropdown.aspx

Comment: @Omu do you know if its possible with awesome to allow users to select a top level category from one dropdown and to automatically populate the sub-category with many depth levels? brgds

Comment: @sebastian_h when the value of a parent dropdown changes the children will reload using the new value of the parent as a parameter

Comment: Where do you store the information which links the two lists?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not sure if I understand this correctly. There has to be some sort of relationship between the values to determine which subcompanies belong to what maincompany. So for e.g. when the user selects an option from the main company list you'd have an ajax call to a function which would return the sub companies for that maincompany. Is this how it's working?